# How to distinguish orientation for wR hR constraints variation

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to apply 16:9 or 9:16 aspect ratio constraint to `UIImageView` depending on device orientation, however it looks as it is impossible to identify the orientation through constraint variations for such case due to `wR hR = hR wR`.

How one can deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should

- add two ratio constraints on the view, one that is 16:9 and the other that is 9:16; make sure only one of those has "installed" selected in the attributes inspector in IB;
- add `IBOutlet` references to the two ratio constraints;
- in view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (or the view's `layoutSubviews`), just look at the width and height of the `bounds` and activate constraints accordingly:

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var portraitConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
  @IBOutlet weak var landscapeConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

      let isLandscape = view.bounds.size.width > view.bounds.size.height

      landscapeConstraint.isActive = isLandscape
      portraitConstraint.isActive = !isLandscape
  }
  ```

Comment: Note, it is tempting to override the `traitCollection`, but [Apple discourages this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623514-traitcollection). But if you implement view controller containment, you can have the parent use [`setOverrideTraitCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621406-setoverridetraitcollection). Having said that, I think it's just easier to do it like above.